# Set up a python virtualenv with a specific version of Python

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am trying to get started with Google App Engine. I have python 2.6 installed in my virtual environment which I wanted to use. But Google App Engine supports python2.5. So I want to set up another python virtual environment with python 2.5.

Can you help me how to do exactly that?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 9.10. I am not stuck anywhere. I tried running a sample application on Python 2.6 and it ran fine. But GAE gives me a warning that I am using Python 2.6 and that I should move to Python 2.5. That, I too think, will be wise to avoid any errors due to mismatch of python versions. So I want to make a virtual environment for Python 2.5 for only developing GAE apps. I want to know how to do that?

Answer (score 5):

Virtualenv lets you specify a `python` binary to use instead of the default. On your machine, `python` probably maps to `/usr/bin/python`, which will be a symlink to `/usr/bin/python2.6`. If you've got Python 2.5 installed, it will be `/usr/bin/python2.5`

You can create a virtualenv called `envname` with `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.5 envname`

Answer (score 0):

Do you specifically need a virtual environment?

Why not just [Install Python 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748963/how-do-i-configure-multiple-ubuntu-python-installations-to-avoid-app-engines-ssl) along side your existing 2.6 and just use 2.5 for your GAE development.

Comment: Well to keep things separate, it is always better to install python as a virtual environment so that external packages do not conflict. But, if there is no other way, then I think I will have to do that.